# Insert asterisks around numbers in string using Java

Tags: java

What would be the best way to add asterisks before and after any numbers which appear within a string using Java? Note that multiple digits which appear joined would be interpreted as a single number.

for example, convert this:

```
0this 1is02 an example33 string44
```

to this:

```
*0*this *1*is*02* an example*33* string*44*
```

Comment: Use regular expression replacement with a back reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to a `String#replaceAll()` on your input string, matching on `\d+` and replacing on `*$1*`.  In other words, replace every cluster of digits with that cluster of digits surrounded by asterisks.

```
String input = "0this 1is02 an example33 string44";
input = input.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "*$1*");
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
*0*this *1*is*02* an example*33* string*44*
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester